# I can't connect to my friend's Hamachi MC server

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues, hamachi

So I wanted to join my friend's server but I couldn't. My other two friends that play with us can connect easily but I can't. I've tried a lot of tutorials, disabled my Firewall entirely, uninstalled my antivirus, added ports, edited control panel in Java but it doesn't work. When I want to join it gives me errors like "Timed out" or it will allow me to join but then kicks me out saying "an existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host". I really don't know what to do anymore, does anyone know? Thanks.